# Is there a Google Sheets formula expression that only evaluates when the sheet is edited?

Tags: google-sheets, expression

The title sums it up pretty well. I need a cell of my document to reflect the last time any cell in the document updated. "=now()" doesn't work, because now() is evaluated any time the sheet is evaluated - even if there is no change. This means that even the simple act of hitting the browser's reload button causes now() to update its cell - TWICE!

I'd rather not use the onEdit trigger in script, because that would require that I add that script to 1000+ sheets. I already have a way to edit document through the python sheets API, so it would be fairly easy to automatically add the expression wherever I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Volatile spreadsheet functions are not suitable for timestamps, for the reason you stated.

Use a trigger. You don't need to add a script to each sheet. A single  stand-alone Google Apps Script can automatically install an "on edit" trigger for multiple spreadsheets, using [forSpreadsheet(key) method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forspreadsheetkey). Example:

```
var ids = ['ss_id1', 'ss_id2', ... ];  // array of spreadsheet IDs
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('timestamp').forSpreadsheet(ids[i]).onEdit().create();
}
function timestamp(e) {
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Now, whenever one of the listed spreadsheets is edited, the cell A1 of the sheet that was edited in it will have the time of the edit.

This probably won't work for 1000 triggers, because of [current limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) of 20 triggers per user per script. Looks like you'll need 50 copies of the stand-alone script, which is a stretch but still manageable.

---

Another alternative is to run a scheduled Google Apps Script that retrieves "last modified" dates of spreadsheets in the directory (using DriveApp) and edits those in the spreadsheets.

Yet another is to give up. Maybe you don't need a cell to hold information that is already available in spreadsheet interface, "last edited".